# ES6 destructuring assignment doesn't work in latest Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, destructuring, ecmascript-next

I'm using the following code that works perfectly on [es6fiddle](http://www.es6fiddle.net/ivo2via1/):

```
const o1 = { aa: 11, bb: 22, cc: 33 };
let { aa, ...o2 } = o1;

console.log(o1.aa);
console.log(o2.cc);
```

(purpose of the code above is to remove `aa` element from `o1`, store the rest in `o2`, without mutating `o1`).

It works on web, but when I try to execute this code from my console it doesn't work. I tried with latest node (6.9.1 and 7.1.0), and it doesn't work. When I look at [specs](http://node.green) for these versions, seems like it should work.

Here is error message I got in my console:

```
$ node src/lru-cache.js 
/home/admin/experiments/ct/src/lru-cache.js:2
let { aa, ...o2 } = o1;
          ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3

$ node -v
v6.9.1
```

What's wrong with my configuration and how can I make it work? Thanks!

Comment: Are you calling node with any `--harmony...` flags?

Comment: Thanks, I tried, result is the same

Comment: It's "destructuring", not "destructing". Anyway, your problem is not with destructuring, it's with object rest properties. *Works on web*: what browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you're using is called [object rest properties](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread). It isn't supported by Node.js yet; in fact, the only platform that currently supports it is Babel (see [ES Next compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/#test-object_rest_properties)).